# iOS - Is there a way to block swipe to the right behavior in gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am modifying a module which is basically a standard hidden left menu (swipe to the right to reveal the menu)

The standard behavior of this menu system is that any swipes to the left are blocked, thereby limiting the ability to swipe left to delete a row in a tableview for example.

I've added this code in which successfully opens up the ability to swipe to the left to delete a row in a table.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{

    if([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]])
    {

    }

    return YES;

}
```

Problem is, that it now also allows the menu to open up on any type of swipe to the right.  So for example, if you are scrolling down, but happen to scroll down at a slight angle to the right themenu opens up willy nilly.  Its very annoying

### **The Question**

What would be the proper piece of code to add in here to block swipe right gestures?

It seems the 'return YES' is what is opening up the additional gestures but am struggling to find a way to return NO on a swipe right.  The original code actually had this other part, but it didn't seem to do anything different.

To my eyes, it is the 'RETURN YES' that is opening up the behavior.  If I could find a way to RETURN NO on a swipe to the right that might do it?

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{

    if([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recog = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
        if(recog.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft && [recog.view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) return NO;

    }

    return YES;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick. Add a new `UIGestureRecognizer` to your `UITableView` and add a `selector` to that with nothing inside.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

Of course for the gestureRecognizer's selector:

`- (void)myMethod {}`